# External resources fail to load when using HTML5 cache

Tags: javascript, html, html5-appcache

I'm trying to get app cache to work:

```
CACHE MANIFEST

/css/style.css
/js/colors.js
/js/dropzone.js
/js/jquery.min.js
/js/script.js

/img/icon_analytics.png
/img/icon_exit.png
/img/icon_expand.png
/img/icon_list.png
/img/icon_lock.png
/img/icon_menu.png
/img/icon_more_content.png
/img/icon_settings.png
/img/icon_settings_black.png
/img/svg_icons/close_fullscreen.svg
/img/svg_icons/go_fullscreen.svg
/img/loader.gif
```

But here is what I'm getting in the console:

```
GET https://www.google.com/jsapi net::ERR_FAILED
(index):517 Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
(index):524 GET http://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js net::ERR_FAILED
0.s3.envato.com/files/115114837/profile.jpg:1 GET https://0.s3.envato.com/files/115114837/profile.jpg net::ERR_FAILED
jquery.min.js:3 GET http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/mnpfi9pxYH-Go5UiibESIpBw1xU1rKptJj_0jans920.woff2 net::ERR_FAILED
```

Apparently, it refuses to load any resources which are not specified in the .appcache file. I even tried to specify only the images, it still throws errors for the stylesheet and all .js files.

What's going on?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add the NETWORK section, like this:

```
CACHE MANIFEST

CACHE:
/css/style.css
/js/colors.js
/js/dropzone.js
/js/jquery.min.js
/js/script.js

/img/icon_analytics.png
/img/icon_exit.png
/img/icon_expand.png
/img/icon_list.png
/img/icon_lock.png
/img/icon_menu.png
/img/icon_more_content.png
/img/icon_settings.png
/img/icon_settings_black.png
/img/svg_icons/close_fullscreen.svg
/img/svg_icons/go_fullscreen.svg
/img/loader.gif

NETWORK:
*
```

Read [more](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/) here.

Comment: Thanks, that got rid of the error. Is there a way to cache those external resources too? I can still see that it downloads this https://www.google.com/jsapi which is a huge library

Comment: From the linked article: "Files listed in this section may come from the network if they aren't in the cache, otherwise the network isn't used, even if the user is online". These should be cached after the first download.